# More blocks in Simulink

Tags: matlab, block, simulink, repeat, subsystem

I have created my own Pi section in Matlab Simulink via SimPowerSystem toolbox recently, but there is a problem if I want to use this subsystem more times, for example 50 times.

Is there any solution to place it in model more gracefully than repeat it?

Comment: You want to repeat a block without repeating a block? I am confused

Comment: "Repeat it" - it means to place it successive, manually. But I am looking for a way to encapsulate it into special subblock where it will be able to set up constant value, for example N, to achiev of required quantity of Pi sections....

Comment: You can copy paste it and it will do that.  There is a block called "subsystem"  where you can put stuff inside,  and then copy paste.  Is that what you are looking for?